# Regexp to find only 6 digit number in text PostgreSQL

Tags: regex, postgresql

I need to build a query in PostgreSQL and am required to find all text entries that contain a 6 digit number (e.g. `000999`, `019290`, `998981`, `234567`, etc). The problem is that the number is not necessary at the begining of the string or at its end.

I tried and didn't work:

- `[0-9]{6}` - returns part of a number with more than 6 digits
- `(?:(?<!\d)\d{6}(?!\d))` - postgresql does not know about lookbehind
- `[^0-9][0-9]{6}[^0-9]`  and variations on it, but to no avail.

Building my own Perl/C function is not really an option as I do not have the skills required.  Any idea what regexp could be used or other tricks that elude me at the moment?

**EDIT**

Input samples:

- `aa 0011527 /CASA` -> should return NOTHING
- `aa 001152/CASA` -> should return `001152`
- `aa001152/CASA` -> should return `001152`
- `aa0011527/CASA` -> should return NOTHING
- `aa001152 /CASA` -> should return `001152`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If PostgreSQL supports word boundaries, use `\b`:

```
\b(\d{6})\b
```

**Edit**:

`\b` in PostgreSQL means `backspace`, so it's not a word boundary.

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/interactive/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-POSIX-REGEXP however, will explain you that you can use `\y` as a word boundary, as it means `matches only at the beginning or end of a word`, so

```
\y(\d{6})\y
```

should work.

```
\m(\d{6})\M
```

*should* also work.

Full list of word matches in PostgreSQL regex:

```
Escape  Description
\A      matches only at the beginning of the string (see Section 9.7.3.5 for how this differs from ^)
\m      matches only at the beginning of a word
\M      matches only at the end of a word
\y      matches only at the beginning or end of a word
\Y      matches only at a point that is not the beginning or end of a word
\Z      matches only at the end of the string (see Section 9.7.3.5 for how this differs from $)
```

**New edit:**

Based on your edit, you should be able to do this:

```
(^|[^\d])(\d+)([^\d]|$)
```

Comment: I think the requirement is that string may contain other characters also.

Comment: @NaveedS Since we didn't use `^` or `$`, it will match at any place in a string.

Comment: @NaveedS Yes, the string may contain other strings. Also, PostgreSQL has following boundaries: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3825676/postgresql-regex-word-boundaries. <br/> I tried your solution, but didn't work. I added some samples in my question.

Comment: @h2ooooooo My final query is in my answer, but it would've not been possible without your suggestions. Marked as answer and thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

Using what @h2ooooooo proposed I managed to create the following query:

```
SELECT cleantwo."ID",cleantwo."Name",cleantwo."Code"
FROM
(
SELECT cleanone."ID",cleanone."Name",unnest(cleanone."Code") as "Code" -- 3. unnest all the entries received using regexp_matches (get all combinations)
FROM 
(
SELECT sd."ID", sd."Name", regexp_matches(sd."Name", '(^|[^\d])(\d+)([^\d]|$)')
    as "Code"
FROM "T_SOME_DATA" sd
WHERE substring(sd."Name" from 1 for 15) ~('(^|[^\d])(\d+)([^\d]|$)') -- 1. get all data possible
) as cleanone
WHERE cleanone."Code" IS NOT NULL -- 2. get data where code IS NOT NULL (remove useless entries)
) as cleantwo
WHERE length(cleantwo."Code")=6 -- 4. get only the combinations relevant to my initial requirement (codes with length 6)<br/>
```

It took me a lot of time to find this so I hope it helps someone else in the same situation. Good luck!