# How to split a name into surname plus initials

Tags: regex, postgresql

I have a Postgres table containing names like "Smith, John Albert", and I need to create a view which has names like "Smith, J A".  Postgres has some [regex implementations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3825676/postgresql-regex-word-boundaries) I haven't seen elsewhere.

So far I've got

```
SELECT regexp_replace('Smith, John Albert', '\Y\w', '', 'g');
```

which returns

```
S, J A
```

So I'm thinking I need to find out how to make the replace start part-way into the source string.

Comment: Run your regex only on the second part after comma

Comment: Try `(^\w+)|\Y\w` and replace with `\1`

Comment: Does that work?

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew, it does work, thank you!

Comment: If you prefer me to post the answer please let know.

Comment: I could accept it if you did. It's the best solution to the problem.  Could you include an explanation of the `\1`?

Comment: @bub - of course! That's so much more obvious (to me) this morning than it was late last night :)

Comment: I posted with some explanations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [regex used in PostgreSQL](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/tree/master/src/backend/regex) is actually implemented using a software package written by Henry Spencer. It is not odd, it has its own advantages, peculiarities.

One of the differences from the usual NFA regex engines is the word boundary. Here, `\Y` matches a non-word boundary.  The rest of the patterns you need are quite known ones.

So, you need to use `'^(\w+)|\Y\w'` pattern and a `'\1'` replacement.

**Details**:

- `^` -  start of string anchor
- `(\w+)` - [**Capturing group**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) 1 matching 1+ word chars (this will be referred to with `\1` from the replacement pattern)
- `|` - or
- `\Y\w` - a word char that is preceded with another word character.

The `\1` is called a [replacement **numbered backreference**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/replacebackref.html), that just puts the value captured with Group 1 into the replacement result.

Comment: I meant "odd" as in different to the norm, but point taken, it also implies inferiority. Question edited.

Answer (score 2):

The original idea is by Wiktor Stribiżew:

```
SELECT regexp_replace('Smith, John Albert', '^(\w+)|\Y\w', '\1', 'g');

 regexp_replace
----------------
 Smith, J A
(1 row)
```

Comment: And it is my regex in fact. The second group makes no sense as  it is not referred to from the replacement pattern.

Answer (score 1):

As @bub suggested:

```
t=# SELECT concat(split_part('Smith, John Albert',',',1),',',regexp_replace(split_part('Smith, John Albert',',',2), '\Y\w', '', 'g'));
   concat
------------
 Smith, J A
(1 row)
```

Comment: Works fine and was first in, but is less elegant than @Wiktor Stribiżew's solution, so I'll accept Laurenz Albe's one. Thank you

Comment: @OutstandingBill sure thing