# Regex to match different groups depending on string content

Tags: regex, postgresql

**Requirement**

I have a Postgres column containing values in two forms: personal and corporate names.  Personal names contain a comma while corporate names do not.

```
_owner_titlecase
-------------------------
McCartney, James Paul
Lennon, John Winston Ono
Harrison, George
Starkey, Richard
The Beatles
```

I have to produce a query which abbreviates the personal names only, like this:

```
regexp_replace
-------------------------
McCartney, J P
Lennon, J W O
Harrison, G
Starkey, R
The Beatles
```

**Background**

After some performance tests, I've realised I can't use `CASE` to treat the two row types differently (as in `CASE WHEN _owner_titlecase ~ ',' regexp_replace...`).  So I'm hoping there's a way to write a single regex which can treat the two types differently.

I [previously asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41958267/how-to-split-a-name-into-surname-plus-initials) about how to handle the initials part of personal names, and am now using `(^\w+)|\Y\w` regex as follows:

```
, regexp_replace(_owner_titlecase
    , '(^|;\s+)(\w+)|\Y\w'
    , '\1', 'g')
```

Now I've widened the scope to look at the corporate names, of course `The Beatles` is being abbreviated to `The B`.

The `\Y` is a Postgres regex character class which I learned about [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3825676/postgresql-regex-word-boundaries) which matches only at a point that is not the beginning or end of a word.  While the special Postgres classes look like they could be of use in this situation, it would actually be useful to stick with regex features which are universal, so I can test them in places like regex101.com.  Currently my only Postgres test platforms are somewhat awkward and provide no debugging help.

The whole story is that we have a CartoDB map upon which we want to superimpose a layer containing property owner names.  Some properties are close together and the list of owner names can be long, hence the need to abbreviate.

Comment: I believe you may use `^([^,]*)$|(^|;\s+)(\w+)|\Y\w` pattern and replace with `'\1\2\3'`

Comment: Thank you again @Wictor.  This works for most personal names.  It doesn't quite get `O'Brien, John Andrew` right.

Comment: I maybe don't understand the problem correctly, but couldn't you just filter with a `where`-statement before like `WHERE name LIKE '%,%'`

Comment: @Fallenhero, that wouldn't work because it would stop the corporate names from appearing in the results, and hence on the map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest that you should use

```
regexp_replace(_owner_titlecase,
     '^([^,]*)$|(^|;\s+)([\w\u0027]+)|\Y\w',
     '\1\2\3', 'g')
```

The point is that you only need to remove any word char that is preceded with a word char, and keep everything else. So, any exception (text you need to  keep) can be added as a captured alternative branch *before* the pattern you need to remove.

The `^([^,]*)$`  part only matches and captures a string that consists of 0+ chars other than `,`, and with `\1` you restore it in the replacement result.

Comment: The `O'Brien, Andrew John` problem (which comes back as `O'B, A J`) is easily fixed by extending the pattern slightly to `^([^,]*)$|(^|;\s+)([\w\u0027]+)|\Y[\w\u0027]`. I'm not sure which side of the `|` is responsible though.

Comment: I think the `\u0027` in the last branch is not necessary. See [`^([^,]*)$|(^|;\s+)([\w\u0027]+)|\Y\w` regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/CbydIO/1). It looks like that is enough. Names cannot have `O'` prefix.