# Ruby variable in Postgresql Regex

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a table named `orders` with a column named `comment` in it.

I have a list of `order ids`, and I want to search through all the `comment` to see which `order` has referenced them.

So far I have worked out the regex part of the sql

```
Order.where('comment ~ \'\s\d{5}\' OR comment ~ \'^\d{5}\'')
     .where("comment LIKE '%?%'", order_id)
```

But I can't seem to work out a way to make the query more flexible to find `order_ids` that have different length other than 5

Is it possible to make `{5}` more dynamic, to something like `{#{order_id.to_s.length}}`?

**UPDATE**
Just ran into this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3825705/1301840)
Using a boundary match would work even better for this case.

`Order.where('comment ~ \'\y?\y\'', order_id)`
Would do the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can pass digit_count

```
digit_count = order_id.to_s.length
Order.where('comment ~ \'\s\d{?}\' OR comment ~ \'^\d{?}\'', digit_count, digit_count)
```

if you are looking for specific order_id

```
Order.where("comment ~ \'\s#{order_id}\s\'")
```