# Find in column field same tags PostgreSQL

Tags: python, regex, database, postgresql

Hi I need find same tags in column field.

My query:

```
select *, from 
(SELECT *,  string_agg(DISTINCT "tags".tag, ',') as tags_field
            from restaurants
            left JOIN tags on rest.rest_id = tags.rest_id
            GROUP by rest_id) x
```

it return a lot of columns, I leave just needed, and ask for help with it

```
rest_id  tags_field
1        "Sussi,Burger"
2        "Sussi,Pizza"
3        "Seafood"
4        "Sussi,Vok,Beer"
5        "Sussi, Pizza"
```

from back-end I will search tags like `Sussi` in this case it should return 1,2,4,5 rows
if I need `Sussi,Pizza` it should return only 1,2 , and the sequence shouldn't matter.

for example I tried it on sqlite there I solved it by regexp, but how make same on posgtresql

```
tags_field REGEXP ^(?=.*\bPizza\b)(?=.*\bSushi\b)
```

Comment: Does [this](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/functions-matching.html) answer your question?

Comment: I tried to use regexp_matches(tags_field , '(Sussi)(Pizza)') , but it return empty field

Comment: `^(?=.*\yPizza\y)(?=.*\ySushi\y)`, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3825676/postgresql-regex-word-boundaries

Comment: I take it this is not a Python regex engine. Why use it's tag ?

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew thx you, but I can't find method which I can use for solve problem

Comment: Use `tags_field ~ ^(?=.*\yPizza\y)(?=.*\ySushi\y)`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew added in the end of query `where tags_field ~* '^(?=.*\ySussu\y)(?=.*\yPizza\y)'` still nothing

Comment: Try `WHERE tags_field ~* '^(?=.*\yPizza\y)(?=.*\ySushi\y)'`. I do not think you want to match `Sussu` in your text.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew oh, typo sorry. I also think maybe it not works because I tried use cyrillic or it not a problem for postgres?

Comment: Try `WHERE tags_field ~* '^(?=.*(?<![[:alnum:]])Pizza(?![[:alnum:]]))(?=.*(?<![[:alnum:]])Sushi(?![[:alnum:]]))'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert the text column into an array and use an array comparison.

```
SELECT *
FROM
    (SELECT rest_id, string_to_array(trim(tags_field), ',') as tags_field FROM data) data
WHERE
    ARRAY['Pizza','Sussi'] <@ tags_field; -- query clause
-- THIS RETURNS
-- 2 {Sussi,Pizza}
```

`<@` means **is contained by**. This means that `tags_field` must have Pizza and Sussi to be true. Since it is an array, the order does not matter. So

```
ARRAY['Sussi','Pizza'] = ARRAY['Pizza','Sussi'] -- for the *is contained by* validation
```

If you use `ARRAY['Sussi'] <@ tags_field`, you'll get ids: 1,2,4,5

This does not search for ' Pizza' because of the space before Pizza.

```
' Pizza' != 'Pizza' -- Remember PostgreSQL is case sensitive and every space matters.
```

To find for every Pizza you would have to pre-process the data and remove unnecessary spaces. **NOT RECOMMENDED BUT POSIBLE**.

```
SELECT *
FROM(
    SELECT 
        rest_id,
        string_to_array(
            trim(-- Remove spaces after and before text
                regexp_replace(
                    regexp_replace(
                        regexp_replace(
                            tags_field,
                            '\s+', ' ', 'g'), -- Replace multiple spaces to one space.
                        ', ',',','g' -- Remove space after coma
                    ),
                    ' ,',',','g' -- Remove space before coma
                )
            ),
            ',' -- Delimitador for array
        )as tags_field 
    FROM data
) data_mod
WHERE
    ARRAY['Pizza','Sussi'] <@ tags_field; -- query clause
-- THIS RETURNS
-- 2 {Sussi,Pizza}
-- 5 {Sussi,Pizza}
```

With the previous query you'll get ids 2 and 5 because there is no longer ' Pizza' with spaces.

The **CORRECT WAY** would be to fix your rogue spaces with an update and much better to use `array` instead of `text` for tags_field, but the `array` part means changing your database structure so... we'll just stay with the update:

```
UPDATE data SET tags_field = trim(-- Remove spaces after and before text
    regexp_replace(
        regexp_replace(
            regexp_replace(
                tags_field,
                '\s+', ' ', 'g'), -- Multiple spaces to one space.
            ', ',',','g' -- remove space after coma
        ),
        ' ,',',','g' -- remove space before coma
    )
);
```

With the update, your query would be:

```
SELECT *
FROM
    (SELECT rest_id, string_to_array(tags_field, ',') as tags_field FROM data) data
WHERE
    ARRAY['Pizza','Sussi'] <@ tags_field;
```

No trim needed.

If you change your table structure and use `array` instead of `text` the query would be easier:

```
SELECT rest_id, tags_field
FROM data
WHERE
    ARRAY['Pizza','Sussi'] <@ tags_field;
```

Comment: After eliminating all those rogue spaces, you should add trim functions to your code to handle your data correctly. It is wrong to leave them be.

Comment: thank you, your solution really helpful, it almost solve my problem, I will test it and make reply about results